# How to integrate Eclipse Dynamic Web Project Folder structure with Tomcat6

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I want to create a web project in Eclipse, but I don't understand the Folder Structure of the project. It is different with the "webapps" folder layout which state in Tomcat6 Folder.
Could anyone tell me which folder I should put web file(like: html, jsp), which folder I should put java source, which folder I should put the servlet file.

Here is the Project in Eclipse:

> ```
> Web Project
>   - build
>   - Webcontent
>       * META-INF
>       * WEB-INF
>          * - scr (not default one)
>          * - classes(not default one)
>          * - web.xml
>   - JavaSource
>       * scr
> ```

now what I did is put .java file into /JavaSource/src , and put .jsp file into /WebProject/WEB-INF, and when I import such as "test.java" into "index.jsp" I write following:

```
<%page import="test.java" %>
```

but it shows error in eclipse.
what is the correct way of organize those files to create a meaningful standard project.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should put *.jsp files under WebProject/WebContent
2. You should put *.java source files under WebProject/JavaSource/src/your/package/name
3. To reference a java class from JSP you need to use its fully qualified name e.g. `<%page import="your.package.name.Test" %>`, where Test is the name of the class located in Test.java in WebProject/JavaSource/src/your/package/name